# Convert local scope to global scope or query by parent attribute

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve all comments which belong to active posts.

I have a local scope on my `Posts` model looking like this.

```
public function scopePublic($query) {
    return $query->whereHas('post', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_public', true);
    });
}
```

Which works fine, but breaks with `PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted` as soon as I want to convert it to a global scope like this:

```
static::addGlobalScope('is_public', function (Builder $builder) {
    return $builder->whereHas('post', function ($q) {
        $q->where('is_public', true);
    });
});
```

My end goal is for all comment queries only to show public comments, unless I specifically ask not to.

I've been through quite a few solutions. I've tried joining the post on the comments, and I tried adding a sub-select to no luck.

```
$builder->addSelect(['is_public' => Post::select('is_private')
   ->whereColumn('id', 'comment.post_id')->limit(1)
]);

$builder->join('posts','posts.id','=','comments.post_id')
    ->where('comments.is_private', false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new class PublicScope

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;

class CommentPublicScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->whereHas('post', function ($q) {
            $q->where('is_public', true);
        });
    }
}
```

Then you can add the global scope

```php
Class Comment extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(new CommentPublicScope);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing that throws `PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted`

Comment: Well, if you call for all the comments you have in the database, and if you have thousands or millions, not a surprise. with scope or without. In all cases, it's unrelated to your question.

Comment: This is not because I am exhausting my memory - this is because of a recursion bug with this code sample. I only have ten comments in my test database, and I am limiting the query to fetching 3.

Comment: where did you add the global scope ?

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank added more precision on where you need to declare the global scope

Comment: Your edit made me realise the mistake - my boot sequence was wrong, causing the scope to mess with another scope.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: appears this was happening due to a ´protected $withCount = ['comments']´ on the posts model.

Comment: ow, that can lead to an infinite loop... I guess that can happen when you use a scope related to another model attribute.

Comment: Yep! Thanks though, now I have something to work with and can fix :)